# Advanced Iteration through an Array

Tags: ruby

I have an array with 100 false values: [false, false, false,....]. The first iteration should replace each false value with a true value. The second should replace every other value in the array with the opposite of what it is. The third should replace every third value in the in the array with the opposite of what it is. And so on.. I was able to accomplish this with while loops. However, I know this can be simplified, but I can't figure it out.

```
array = []
100.times
    array << false
end

i = 1
while i < 100
    j = 0
    while i < array.length
        if array[j] == false
            array[j] = true
        elsif array[j] == true
            array[j] = false
        end
        j += i
    end
    i += 1
end
```

Comment: have you tried `each_with_index.map`?

Comment: You have not stated whether the operation is to be repeated 99 times or 100 times. I mention this only because some answers assumed 99, others 100 (which affects the first element only). I don't think you should clarify, though, as doing so would make some answers undeservedly incorrect.  I mention this mainly to alert readers who compare solutions that they should disregard different results for the first element.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go...

```
a = Array.new(100, false)

(1...a.length).each do |stepsize|
  (0...a.length).step(stepsize) {|i| a[i] = !a[i]}
end
```

An alternative would be:

```
a = Array.new(100, false)

(1...a.length).each do |stepsize|
  (0...a.length).step(stepsize) {|i| a[i] ^= true}
end
```

The `^=` is doing an exclusive or with `true`, so a `true` will toggle to `false` and vice-versa.

Yet another alternative would be to use `Numeric`'s `step` iterator:

```
a = Array.new(100, false)

(1...a.length).each do |stepsize|
  0.step(a.length-1, stepsize) {|i| a[i] ^= true}
end
```

Comment: +1 for using (1) `Array.new(100, false)` (2) Rubyish iteration instead of loop.

Comment: @XiaogeSu Thanks.  I also wanted to take the magic number 100 out of the code except where the array is instantiated.

Comment: @CarySwoveland When I checked by hand, I noted that it should be `[f,t,f]` for 3, and `[f,t,f,f,t]` for 5, which is what the current version produces. Initially I was using double-dots when I should have been using triple-dots.  That meant I iterated one more time than I should, but the `stepsize` was such that it only impacted the first element. I thought I fixed it last night, are you still getting different results with the latest version?

Comment: pjs, please see the comment I left on the question.  I've deleted my earlier comment and will delete this one later.

Answer (score 2):

The first element of the array will be `true` if and only if the number of elements in the array is odd.  Other elements will be `true` if and only if they are perfect squares.

I have assumed the flipping operation is to be performed `n` times, where `n` is the size of the array.  If it is to be `n-1` times, the first element is reversed, but all other elements remain the same.

**Code**

```
def doit(n)
  (0...n).map do |i|
    if i == 0 
      n.odd?
    else   
      m = Math.sqrt(i).floor
      m*m == i
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
doit(9)
  #=> [true, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, false]
doit(10)
 #=> [false, true, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, true]
```

For `n = 100`, the `true` values are at these offsets:

```
doit(100).each_with_index.select { |t,i| t }.map(&:last)
  #=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

**Explanation**

The element at offset `i > 0` will flip between `false` and `true` once for each number `j`, `1 <= j <= i`, where `j` is a divisor of `i` (`i%j.zero?`).  Hence, for `i > 0`, we need only determine if the number of divisors is odd or even. The standard way of computing the number of divisors of a number `n` is as follows:

```
def divisors(n)
  m = Math.sqrt(n).floor
  tot = (1..m).reduce(0) { |t,i| (t += 2) if (n%i).zero?; t }
  tot -= 1 if m*m == n
  tot.odd?
end
```

We need only check numbers `i` up to `m` (`m = Math.sqrt(n).floor`), for if `i` is a divisor of `n`, `n/i` will also be a divisor.  If, however, `m*m == n`, we need to subtract one to avoid double-counting `i = m`.  For this problem we only need to know if the total is even or odd, so we only have to check whether `m*m == n`, since each divisor `i < m` contributes two divisors to the total.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different method, but this way I keep all of the steps that got me to the final calculation.

```
array = 100.times.collect {false}
steps = array.size.times.inject([array]) do |result,mod|
  last = result.last
  result << last.collect.with_index do | x, i |
    (i%(mod+1) == 0) ? (!x) : (x)
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Charlie, could you check your result?  Replacing 100 with 3, I get `=> [[false, false, false], [true, true, true], [false, true, false], [true, true, false]]`.  I believe we want `[true, true, false]`, the last element of your array.

Comment: It is the last element of my array :) As you said elsewhere it's unclear if we would want to do 2 or 3 iterations with a size 3 array. It's also unclear if "every other" means the first element we flip is the 0-indexed element or the 1-indexed element. :)

Comment: Ah, in that case considering tacking `.last` to the end up the penultimate line.  (I can't resist using that word whenever the opportunity presents itself.)

Answer (score 0):

```
array = Array.new(100, false)
array.each_index do |i|
  i += 1
  array.each_index{|j| array[j] ^= true if (j % i).zero?}
end
```